# sql server cannot execute duplicate query even after 1 hour..keeps on loading it

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query as below to find duplicates in my table which contains more than 10,00,000 data with 10 fields. When I try to execute the query, it keeps on loading and loading for more than one hour but it cannot complete executing it.
When I try the same query with a similar table of just 100 records, it works fine.

(all column datatype is nchar)

I wonder then how I can use this for data of more than 10,00,000.

```
select * from table1 as L
where (select count(*) from table1
where L.date + L.time + L.color + L.supplier = table1.date +
table1.time + table1.color + table.supplier and table1.variety = 'dark' 
and date between '01062012' and '30062012') > 1
```

Comment: Sounds like your select statement is blocked by some other transaction. In the default installation of SQL Server writers will block readers.

Comment: Please add table structure for better understanding of your problem.

Comment: I have some doubts about `L.date + L.time + L.color + L.supplier = table1.date +
table1.time + table1.color + table.supplier`. it can be equal with diffrent values.

Comment: Not only, it also forces table scan and creating strings -TERRIBLE CODE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***DON'T*** use `L.date + L.time + L.color + L.supplier` = `table1.date +
table1.time + table1.color + table.supplier`  Doing so will MURDER any ability to use indexes in the join.

```
select * from table1 as L
where (select count(*)
         from table1
        where table1.date       = L.date
          and table1.color      = L.color
          and table1.supplier   = L.supplier
          and table1.variety    = 'dark'
          and table1.date between '01062012' and '30062012'
     )
     > 1
```

Also, ensure that your table has an index covering all the join fields *(variety, color, supplier, date)*.

There are other options for finding duplicates, such as using `ROW_NUMBER()`, but we would need to know more about your table structure (unique id field, etc) and what does (and does not) constitute a duplicate.

Comment: Doing field-by-field matching may not give the same set of results, though: assuming string columns, `'ABC'+'DE'='AB'+'CDE'` is true, while `'ABC'='AB' AND 'DE'='CDE'` is false.

Comment: Bad design then - but this is a fundamental issue on the game. Right now that is full table scan, no index, heavy string manupulation which means no performance. Point.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight - I agree, but I would contend that's an issue in the OPs example that is corrected by this methodology.  Therefor, this will give more reliable results and much more quickly.

Comment: @Dems - thank you. your query worked for me but it still takes at least 2 minutes to execute it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about your table structure though. Seems on extreme load your tables are getting locked. Try some hint as mentioned below.

APART from this try removing * and read records that are needed for your execution.

```
select * from table1 as L WITH(NOLOCK)
where (select count(1) from table1 WITH(NOLOCK)
where L.date + L.time + L.color + L.supplier = table1.date +
table1.time + table1.color + table.supplier and table1.variety = 'dark' 
and date between '01062012' and '30062012') > 1
```

Hope it will solve your problem.

Cheers

Comment: it doesn't work either...but again I have come to know something new called with(NoLock). I will look into it.

Answer (score 0):

I am a newbie and my suggestion may not be proper but if would have being at your place i would have used SSIS for the same. I would have used script component in ssis and perform the operations